# How many translations of "ichigo" are there?

Tags: translation, homonyms

"Ichigo" can be the pronunciation of a person's name (as in the cartoon "Bleach"), or words meaning "strawberry", "one and five", or a part of the word "一期一会". Are there any additional meanings of "ichigo"? Are these words homonyms or do they have different tones?

Comment: Related: [Can I write Japanese name “Midori” this way - 緑?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2553/542)

Comment: How many "translations" or how many "meanings"? If you start thinking about translations, the number would depend on the destination language(s). `苺` can be "strawberry", "fragaria", ..., `一` can be "one", "uno", "yi", ..., .

Answer (score 2):

We have three words in everyday vocabulary according to dictionaries.

- 苺 strawberry (pitch accent in Tokyo dialect: Low-High-High)
- 一語 one word (LHL)
- 一期 a whole life (usually used in the compound word 一期一会 LHH-L(H)HH?)

Also we have:

- 一五 one, five (when reading aloud the numbers separately).

参考 http://accent.u-biq.org/i.html

Answer (score 1):

It's mainly down to the myriad readings of the kanji that are available. For instance Ichigo (the name you reference) may not use the same kanji as 一五 (one, five)

Note: I'm not a fan of Bleach, so I wouldn't know if Ichigo was spelt in kanji or kana.

Using my dictionary, I'll pull out 5 random kanji that can be read as Ichi or Go

Ichi can be any of these kanji (took the first 5 kanji only):

- 一
- 位置
- 市
- 壱
- 居ち

Go can be any of these kanji (took the first 5 kanji only):

- 語
- 後
- 五
- 御
- 誤
- 伍

Obviously, the combinations of Ichi and Go will be quite small, but since you didn't specify whether you wanted a list of the possible combinations or just all of the different readings for these characters.

Obviously the list of combinations of these characters that make up meaningful names will be even shorter. But you have to remember that not every Japanese person's name is made with kanji only. Some people (I've met several like this) have kana only given names. Again, you didn't specify whether you wanted just names (either given or family) that could be spelt, in romaji, with the characters "ichigo"

The thing with asking these types of questions, in my opinion, is that there are hundreds of ways to convert a romaji word into something from a Japanese dictionary.

These, obviously don't include the kana readings of ichi (いち and イチ) and go (ご and ゴ)

Someone with a higher level of knowledge will be able to provide you with a better and more detailed answer. I don't wish for this post/answer to come across as pedantic, so I apologise if that is how it came across.

Comment: What is 居ち (in modern Japanese)?

Comment: Must "ichigo" be written by one of the  combinations of kanji listed there? For example, can someone simply say that "陽" is read as "ichigo" ?

Comment: These where all examples. They might not make sense, I was just pointing out that if you ask "how many ways are there to write this Japanese word (in romaji characters) in Japanese script?" that there are going to be lots of different combinations.