# Does 'yuki' really mean happiness?

Tags: meaning, names

Besides the obvious 'snow', someone listed the name Yuki on a name website as also meaning happiness, blessing, or good fortune using the characters 幸き. Dictionaries list that 幸 can become こ / さき / さし / さっ / とも / ひろ / みゆき / ゆ / ゆき / よし. Yu and Yuki are listed at the end, but is it accurate to say that this name means happiness?

Comment: I think that the most common word to happiness is 「幸せ」 which share the same kanji with 「幸き」. I'm not exactly sure, but it seems likely!

Comment: This is a case of [nanori](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanori) where a kanji can have specialized readings in Japanese names. For example, [元渕 幸(Yuki Motobuchi)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%85%83%E6%B8%95%E5%B9%B8)

Comment: @AndrewT.  In your example, Yuki did not need the き character. Can it be spelled either way as 幸き or just 幸 with more or less the same idea, depending on what the person wants?

Comment: AFAIK, it's rare ([but possible](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/6744/)) to mix kanji with hiragana/katakana in someone's name; usually, they just use either kanji 幸, or hiragana/katakana ゆき/ユキ, but not 幸き. So, to answer your question directly: yes, it's possible to use either (though the former looks weird to me, but I'm not a native speaker). On the other hand, all the readings stated in the question can be represented by a single character 幸 if it's used in a name.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Does 'yuki' really mean happiness?

I feel like this is a loaded question, so let's break it down.

- The character 幸 means "happiness".
- If the name ゆき is written using this kanji, then it also means "happiness".
- ゆき by itself does not necessarily mean anything—ゆ and き simply represent sounds.

  - However, context could easily provide a meaning to those sounds, and ゆき as a word has several different meanings.
  - If you knew someone named 'Yuki' who spelled it simply ゆき (or possibly ユキ), it might not have any meaning.
- If you see someone's name written as 幸, [you'd be wise not to assume it's read as ゆき (or anything else)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/5532).

Answer (score 8):

The question is asking about the word `yuki` and its relation to the meaning `happiness`. Kanji spellings do not always reflect the meaning of a word.

Looking up `yuki` in several monolingual dictionaries, we find other words pronounced `yuki`, such as 裄 (some part of a kimono) or 斎木 (some tree used in rituals), but these do not seem to be related.

The word 幸 with the reading `saki` or `sachi` means `happiness`,  `fortune`, `luck` (or [products of the sea](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%B5%B7%E5%B9%B8-441491#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)). This reading is closer to `yuki`, but offers no explanation how we would get from `saki` to `yuki`.

Now, checking a kanji dictionary for 幸, it lists the reading `miyuki` as a kunyomi (Japanese) reading for the kanji; and elaborates on its meaning:

> みゆき。天子が出かけることをいう敬語。▽思いがけないさいわいの意から。 (学研漢和大字典)

That is, `miyuki` is a respectful expression referring to the emperor going outside or taking a trip. Furthermore, the dictionary attributes the kanji spelling to it being a metaphor for likening the emperor showing himself in public as an unexpected ― but *fortunate* ― happening.

The word `miyuki` seems to me to be a combination of the honoric prefix 御【mi】 and 行【yu】き (noun form of `yuku`, to go). Checking a dictionary such as the 大辞泉, they seem to agree.

This also nicely separates the word into the two parts `mi` and `yuki`. So my assumption is that the reading `yuki` derives from a shortening of `miyuki`. In this case, I'd say it is related to happiness, but does not mean that.

As for personal names, if the parents give their child a name that is read with `yuki` and spelled with `幸`, there is a good chance they intend the meaning of `happiness` and I guess in that sense it could be said to mean happiness.

Comment: This answer is the most accurate and complete one IMO.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that sometimes parents are very creative with their use of kanji when naming children.  You see a similar thing happen in the United States when people start getting creative with the spelling of names (like Aleks instead of Alex).

Jisho.org says the [kanji](https://jisho.org/search/%E5%B9%B8%20%23kanji) means the following: `happiness, blessing, fortune`.

You ask:

> Yu and Yuki are listed at the end, but is it accurate to say that this name means happiness?

I say that you are quite possibly right, but it may be difficult to know for sure without having talked to the parents.  I would imagine that your understanding is correct though.