# Can I use Kanji for my first name?

Tags: kanji, names

I would like to use Kanji for my first name (Winri) when I go to Japan. Is this okay to do? If so, what characters would go into the name?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is or is not a dupe -- but there's been related discussion in the past: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29473/as-a-foreigner-with-a-japanese-name-what-are-the-implications-of-writing-my-nam

Answer (score 3):

Of course, you can use Kanji for your first name. I think your first name is ウィンリ written in Japanese so you can use kanji character like ウ, イン, リ.

There are many kanji and you can choose them as you like. I advise you to choose kanji which have good meaning.

How about 宇(ウ)院(イン)理(リ)?

Comment: Would it be implied to use onyomi, so the Kanji are unlikely to be mispronounced?

Comment: Yes, kanji idioms which are read by onyomi are the leading case of the eadings

Comment: When using kanji for name, can you use also rare or uncommon types of pronounce?

Comment: Any time. If you can formally use kanji for name, you can register your kanji name in residence card.