# The characters of the name Hiro

Tags: translation, names

My name is Hiro, but I have no idea how to write it in japanese. If you could help me with that, it would be great since most online websites aren't very helpful.

Comment: There are multiple ways. Did you look at people named Hiro and check how they write it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [As a foreigner with a Japanese name, what are the implications of writing my name in katakana or kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29473/as-a-foreigner-with-a-japanese-name-what-are-the-implications-of-writing-my-nam)

Answer (score 3):

ヒロ (in katakana)

or

ひろ (in hiragana)

If you want to write it in kanji, there are plural candidates.

Answer (score 0):

My real given name is 公大{きみひろ}. Feel free to use a kanji 大{ひろ} for ad-hoc usage until you can find a nicer one since it does not have many stroke counts. It's easy to remember. Japanese might read 大{ひろし}　though, It might be better than nothing.

Yeah, for sure, you don't have to stick to literal pronunciation. It is up to you to use phonetic equivalent 英雄{ひろ}("Hero" in Engish) called 当{あ}て字{じ} in Japanese.

Good Luck with that. Since I am far from an expert on Onomancy, I can't give best stroke counts for you.