# How should I write my name with an American first name and Japanese last name?

Tags: orthography, names

I generally understand that proper Japanese uses Hiragana and Katakana is for slang/foreign words. Given that, my first name is super American but my last name is Japanese. Would I then make my first name Katakana and last name Hiragana?

(I haven't touched Kanji yet, so let's just stick to those two for now!)

Comment: Presumably "Aaron Higa" is your actual name, and not just a user handle on here?

Comment: Katakana entirely would be the general practice.

Comment: Unless you know the Kanji that make up your family name (because there are variations!) you're better off sticking to all Katakana.

Answer (score 4):

Foreigners's names are usually written in katakana, even when their names are based in Japanese.

For example, Michio Kaku is a Japanese-American with a full Japanese name, and yet his name is usually written in katakana.
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/ミチオ・カク](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9F%E3%83%81%E3%82%AA%E3%83%BB%E3%82%AB%E3%82%AF)

Other examples:
[https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/日系アメリカ人の一覧](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E7%B3%BB%E3%82%A2%E3%83%A1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%AB%E4%BA%BA%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E8%A6%A7)

But if you are living or wants to live in Japan you can adopt a 通称名, a name to be used inside Japan.
Then you can adopt a name in kanji, if you want to. You can for example change Higa to the original kanji name.

Answer (score 1):

If you live in Japan, I think it would depend on your nationality.

If you are a Japanese national, then you may use the Kanji surname in **official** documents because that is how it's supposed to be recorded in your Family Register (called 戸籍{こせき}), *unless* for some reason it was purposedly registered in Katakana, which is kinda strange if one of your parents is Japanese.

If you are a non-Japanese national, it has to be in Katakana in **official** documents. If you still want to use Kanji, you may after you register a legal alias (called 通称名{つうしょうめい}) in the municipality that you live in, but there could be limitations to its usage.

For **non-official** documents, I don't think it will be a big issue if you use Kanji, but then it might be confusing later on to remember which name you used where.

I tried to look for official (Japanese Government) sources in English but couldn't find any. You can get more information from below references:

1. https://www.japan-guide.com/forum/quereadisplay.html?0+162645
2. [As a foreigner with a Japanese name, what are the implications of writing my name in katakana or kanji?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/29473/as-a-foreigner-with-a-japanese-name-what-are-the-implications-of-writing-my-nam)

Comment: May I ask why the -1?