# Kanji for Midori

Tags: kanji, names

Please, if someone could help me... My grandfather was japanese, and he named me as Midori, since I was the youngest of 4 girls, he said that the meaning of Midori was little flower sprout, since I was the smallest of my sisters. But he never taught me the Kanji of my name, and I don't speak japanese.
He passed away a couple of years ago and I miss him so much, that I would like to discover the kanji of my name... I would appreciate so much if someone could help me with this...

Comment: Related or duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2553/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/21228/9831